# Syntax Error: Unexpected "&lt" on Line 1

Tags: php

Not sure why it's doing this, but I'm getting the following syntax error: "Unexpected "&lt" on Line1".

I can't seem to find out what is the problem, I've already tried troubleshooting the problem earlier before posting this.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/admin/classes/classes.php');        // Include local class lib

$sess = new SessionData();      // Creates session object
//$sess->CheckValidFBSession();

if($sess->CheckValidSession()){         
    header('Location: home.php');
}

$log= new log($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], $_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ); 
$stats=new Statistics();
$totalusers=$stats->totalscope();

?>
<html xmlns:fb="//www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<style>  

  .title {
    color:#000000;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .larger {
    color:#000000;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .larger-a {
    //color:#D19160;
    color:#538ADC;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .larger-a:hover {
    //color:#FF0000;
    color:#77C9F3;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:underline;
  }

  select {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
  }

  .white {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .blue {
    color:#3B5998;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  } 

  .red {
    color:#FF0000;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .menu {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .menu:hover {
    color:#77C9F3;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .alternate {
    color:#3B5998;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .alternate:hover {
    color:#000000;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:underline;
  }

  a {
    //color:#D19160;
    color:#538ADC;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  a:hover {
    //color:#FF0000;
    color:#77C9F3;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:underline;
  }

  .bordertable {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #3B5998;
    border-style: solid;
  }

  .dashedtable {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #3B5998;
    border-style: dashed;
  }

  .bottomborder {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #3B5998;
    border-top-width:0px;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-right-width:0px;
    border-left-width:0px;
  }

  .one-column {
    color:#000000;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #3B5998;
    border-top-width:1px;
    border-bottom-width:0px;
    border-right-width:1px;
    border-left-width:1px;
  }

  .text {
    font-Family: Serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .td0 {
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#D9DFEA;
    border: 0;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .td1 {
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#86A1CE;
    border: 0;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  }    

  .schedule_table {
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
  }

  .top-border {
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #3B5998;
  }

  .schedule {
    color:#000000;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#000000;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .border-td {
    color:#000000;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#3B5998;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  td {
    color:#000000;
    border: 0;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .inputtext {
    border:double;
    border-width:1;
    border-color:#555555;
    background-color:#D9DFEA;
    font-size:11px;
    color: #000000;
    font-Family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  .inputsubmit {
    border-style:solid;
    border-top-width:1px;
    border-bottom-width:2px;
    border-right-width:2px;
    border-left-width:1px;
    border-top-color:#D9DFEA;
    border-bottom-color:#3B5998;
    border-right-color:#3B5998;
    border-left-color:#D9DFEA;
    background-color:#538ADC;
    font-family:Tahoma, arial;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:none;
  }
  a img{
    border:none !important;
}
#container{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:500px;
    padding:40px;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#fff;
}

#lightbox h2{
    margin:0 0 1em 0;
}
#lightbox h3{
    color:#FF713F;
}
#lightbox.done p{
    color:#333;
}

#form{
    text-align:left;
    margin:25px;
}
#form ul{
    list-style:none;
}
#form li{
    margin:0 0 1em 0;
}
#form textarea{
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
}

#definition{
    margin:25px;
}
.highlight{
    background-color:#FEFFAF;
}
#lightbox{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    z-index:9999;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:-220px 0 0 -250px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    background:#FDFCE9;
    text-align:left;
}
#lightbox[id]{
    position:fixed;
}

#overlay{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:5000;
    background-color:#000;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
#overlay[id]{
    position:fixed;
}

#lightbox.done #lbLoadMessage{
    display:none;
}
#lightbox.done #lbContent{
    display:block;
}
#lightbox.loading #lbContent{
    display:none;
}
#lightbox.loading #lbLoadMessage{
    display:block;
}

#lightbox.done img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

  <!--
  #8EA7C5 - blue
  #D9DFEA - grey
  59 89 152                (#3B5998)
  217 223 234              (#D9DFEA)
  83 138 220 - link normal (#538ADC)
  119 201 243 - link down  (#77C9F3)
  -->
  </style>


    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId   : '<?php echo $sess->fbappid; ?>',
          session : <?php echo json_encode($sess->fbsession); ?>, // don't refetch the session when PHP already has it
          status  : true, // check login status
          cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
         xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
        });

      };

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>


<title>Kuarrel | Welcome to Kuarrel!</title> 
 <meta name="description" content="Kuarrel is an online directory that connects people from throughout the world." /> 
<meta name="keywords" content="kuarrel, chaibear, chai, sa-mp, sa:mp, 2014" /> 
<meta name="Generator" content="JB engine designed" /> 
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" /> 
<meta name="OriginalPublicationDate" content="2014/03/12/01:37:22">
<meta name="Headline" content="Kuarrel | Welcome to Kuarrel!"> 
<meta name="IFS_URL" content="/index.php"> 
<meta name="contentFlavor" content="PAGE"> 
<meta name="CPS_SITE_NAME" content="Kuarrel | Welcome to Kuarrel"> 
<meta name="CPS_SECTION_PATH" content="Index"> 
<meta name="CPS_ASSET_TYPE" content="STY"> 
<meta name="CPS_PLATFORM" content="HighWeb"> 
<meta name="CPS_AUDIENCE" content="US"> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Kuarrel is an  online directory that connects people from throughout the world."> 
<meta property="og:type" content="website"> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Kuarrel is an online directory that connects people from throughout the world.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.kuarrel.tk/images/logo-right.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.kuarrel.tk/index.php"> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Kuarrel">
  <!-- sO3vWw3hwrnxdrwPGTKy2ZOW6yU -->
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
    };
    (function() {
   var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
   e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
   document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
  </script>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=194568130593245&amp;xfbml=1"></script>

<center> 
<table class="bordertable" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=700> 
  <tr><td> 
      <table class="bottomborder" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=100%> 
      <tr><td width=350 bgcolor=#3B5998> 
          <img src='images/logo-left.jpg'></td> 
          <td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=100%><tr><td> 
          <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=100%> 
          <tr><td><a href='register.php'><img alt='Register' src='images/logo-right.jpg' border=0></a></td> 
          <td width=100% bgcolor=#3B5998>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr> 
          <tr><td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 border=0 width=100%><tr height=21> 
          <!--<td bgcolor=#3B5998 width=10>&nbsp;</td>--> 
 <?PHP

            if(!$sess->CheckValidSession()){            
                include('modules/default/topnav.php');
            }else{
                include('modules/loggedin/topnav.php');       
            }
            ?>                   <td bgcolor=#3B5998 width=100%>&nbsp;</td> 
          </tr></table></td> 
          </tr></table> 
      </td></tr></table> 
  </td></tr> 
  <tr><td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 border=0 width=100%> 
      <tr><td valign=top> 
      <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=105> 
        <tr><td> 
 <?PHP

            if(!$sess->CheckValidSession()){            
                include('modules/default/leftnav.php');
            }else{
                include('modules/loggedin/leftnav.php');          
            }
            ?>
                      </td></tr>  
      </table> 
      </td><td width=595 valign=top> 
        <table class="bordertable" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1 width=100%><tr><td> 

<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 border=0 width=100%> 
<tr><td class='white' bgcolor=#3B5998>Welcome to Kaurrel!</td></tr></table><center><p class='title'>[ Welcome to Kaurell ]<br>
&nbsp;<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=95%>
<tr><td class='larger'><?=(!empty($_GET['error']));?>"<span style='color:red;font-size:16px;'>Facebook login has been disabled for today, please try again tomorrow.</span><br><br>Kaurell is an online directory that connects people from Facebook through social networks at colleges.
<p>We have opened up Kaurell for popular consumption at <b>all colleges and universities</b>. If you are not part of a college or university, you will be added to the default Kaurell network.
<p>Your account is limited to your own college or university. 
<p>You can use Kaurell to:
<br>&nbsp;<b>&#8226;</b>&nbsp; Search for people at your school
<br>&nbsp;<b>&#8226;</b>&nbsp; Find out who are in your classes
<br>&nbsp;<b>&#8226;</b>&nbsp; Look up your friends' friends
<br>&nbsp;<b>&#8226;</b>&nbsp; See a visualization of your social network

<p>To get started, click below to register with your Facebook account.<!--<br><font size="+1">Join the <?=$totalusers?> people at Kaurell today.</font>-->



<center>
<?php if(strlen($_SESSION['notpartofacollege'])>2){
echo "<b>".$_SESSION['notpartofacollege']."</b>";
}
?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<center><input class='inputsubmit' type="button" value='Register' onclick='javascript:document.location="register.php";'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class='inputsubmit' type="button" value=' Login ' onclick='javascript:document.location="login.php";'>
<br>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>  </td></tr></table> 




  </td></tr></table> 
  <center> 
  <?PHP include('modules/default/bottomnav.php');   ?>
  </center><br> 
  </td></tr></table>
```

Thanks to anyone who can figure out what's going on here!

Answer (score 1):

try to correct

```
<?=(!empty($_GET['error']))?
```

to

```
<?=(!empty($_GET['error']));?>
```

also  `</span><br><br>":""?>`  to  `</span><br><br>`

Comment: Still getting the error. I also tried uploading it to my website now and the page is completely white and blank with nothing at all on it, not even in the source code section...@rakesh-sharma

Comment: I fixed that, but my page is still appearing blank for some reason. I'm going to update it with my whole code. @rakesh-sharma