# PHP White/Blank Page

Tags: php

After uploading this to my web-server, I go to the web address and everything is just white/blank, even the source code has nothing in it...Maybe some syntax errors?

I can't seem to find out what is the problem, I've already tried troubleshooting the problem earlier before posting this.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/admin/classes/classes.php');        // Include local class lib

$sess = new SessionData();      // Creates session object
//$sess->CheckValidFBSession();

if($sess->CheckValidSession()){         
    header('Location: home.php');
}

$log= new log($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], $_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ); 
$stats=new Statistics();
$totalusers=$stats->totalscope();

?>
<html xmlns:fb="//www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">


    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId   : '<?php echo $sess->fbappid; ?>',
          session : <?php echo json_encode($sess->fbsession); ?>, // don't refetch the session when PHP already has it
          status  : true, // check login status
          cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
         xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
        });

      };

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>


<title>Kuarrel | Welcome to Kuarrel!</title> 
 <meta name="description" content="Kuarrel is an online directory that connects people from throughout the world." /> 
<meta name="keywords" content="kuarrel, chaibear, chai, sa-mp, sa:mp, 2014" /> 
<meta name="Generator" content="JB engine designed" /> 
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" /> 
<meta name="OriginalPublicationDate" content="2014/03/12/01:37:22">
<meta name="Headline" content="Kuarrel | Welcome to Kuarrel!"> 
<meta name="IFS_URL" content="/index.php"> 
<meta name="contentFlavor" content="PAGE"> 
<meta name="CPS_SITE_NAME" content="Kuarrel | Welcome to Kuarrel"> 
<meta name="CPS_SECTION_PATH" content="Index"> 
<meta name="CPS_ASSET_TYPE" content="STY"> 
<meta name="CPS_PLATFORM" content="HighWeb"> 
<meta name="CPS_AUDIENCE" content="US"> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Kuarrel is an  online directory that connects people from throughout the world."> 
<meta property="og:type" content="website"> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Kuarrel is an online directory that connects people from throughout the world.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.kuarrel.tk/images/logo-right.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.kuarrel.tk/index.php"> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Kuarrel">
  <!-- sO3vWw3hwrnxdrwPGTKy2ZOW6yU -->
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
    };
    (function() {
   var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
   e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
   document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
  </script>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=194568130593245&amp;xfbml=1"></script>

<center> 
<table class="bordertable" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=700> 
  <tr><td> 
      <table class="bottomborder" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=100%> 
      <tr><td width=350 bgcolor=#3B5998> 
          <img src='images/logo-left.jpg'></td> 
          <td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=100%><tr><td> 
          <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=100%> 
          <tr><td><a href='register.php'><img alt='Register' src='images/logo-right.jpg' border=0></a></td> 
          <td width=100% bgcolor=#3B5998>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr> 
          <tr><td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 border=0 width=100%><tr height=21> 
          <!--<td bgcolor=#3B5998 width=10>&nbsp;</td>--> 
 <?PHP

            if(!$sess->CheckValidSession()){            
                include('modules/default/topnav.php');
            }else{
                include('modules/loggedin/topnav.php');       
            }
            ?>                   <td bgcolor=#3B5998 width=100%>&nbsp;</td> 
          </tr></table></td> 
          </tr></table> 
      </td></tr></table> 
  </td></tr> 
  <tr><td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 border=0 width=100%> 
      <tr><td valign=top> 
      <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=105> 
        <tr><td> 
 <?PHP

            if(!$sess->CheckValidSession()){            
                include('modules/default/leftnav.php');
            }else{
                include('modules/loggedin/leftnav.php');          
            }
            ?>
                      </td></tr>  
      </table> 
      </td><td width=595 valign=top> 
        <table class="bordertable" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1 width=100%><tr><td> 

<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 border=0 width=100%> 
<tr><td class='white' bgcolor=#3B5998>Welcome to Kaurrel!</td></tr></table><center><p class='title'>[ Welcome to Kaurell ]<br>
&nbsp;<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=95%>
<tr><td class='larger'><?=(!empty($_GET['error']));?>"<span style='color:red;font-size:16px;'>Facebook login has been disabled for today, please try again tomorrow.</span><br><br>Kaurell is an online directory that connects people from Facebook through social networks at colleges.
<p>We have opened up Kaurell for popular consumption at <b>all colleges and universities</b>. If you are not part of a college or university, you will be added to the default Kaurell network.
<p>Your account is limited to your own college or university. 
<p>You can use Kaurell to:
<br>&nbsp;<b>&#8226;</b>&nbsp; Search for people at your school
<br>&nbsp;<b>&#8226;</b>&nbsp; Find out who are in your classes
<br>&nbsp;<b>&#8226;</b>&nbsp; Look up your friends' friends
<br>&nbsp;<b>&#8226;</b>&nbsp; See a visualization of your social network

<p>To get started, click below to register with your Facebook account.<!--<br><font size="+1">Join the <?=$totalusers?> people at Kaurell today.</font>-->



<center>
<?php if(strlen($_SESSION['notpartofacollege'])>2){
echo "<b>".$_SESSION['notpartofacollege']."</b>";
}
?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<center><input class='inputsubmit' type="button" value='Register' onclick='javascript:document.location="register.php";'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class='inputsubmit' type="button" value=' Login ' onclick='javascript:document.location="login.php";'>
<br>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>  </td></tr></table> 




  </td></tr></table> 
  <center> 
  <?PHP include('modules/default/bottomnav.php');   ?>
  </center><br> 
  </td></tr></table>
```

Comment: enable error reporting in php.ini

Comment: Click F12 and reload the page and tell us what kind of error is given in the Network Section

Comment: Turn on error reporting in php and try.

Comment: One problem is `<?=(!empty($_GET['error']));?>`.

Comment: Please make the snippet smaller. All the CSS is not realted to the problem. So remove it.

Comment: just **FYI** CSS comments are with `/* comment */` not with `<!--comment -->` that is for html only

Comment: Alright, I turned on PHP error checking and boy did it bring up an overwhelming amount of errors within my other pages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax Error: Unexpected "&lt" on Line 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371619/syntax-error-unexpected-lt-on-line-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this at the top of your file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
?>
```

And this at the bottom:

```
<?php
    print_r(array_keys(get_defined_vars()));
    print_r(array_values(get_defined_vars()));
?>
```